# How to really share a Jupyter notebook uploaded to Google Colab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I uploaded a Jupyter .ipynb notebook to Google CoLab using File->Upload Notebook.
Renamed it, made some edits, and saved it.  Great. 
However, when I do "Share"->"Anyone with a link can view", then copy the link and open it in another (or private) browser window, I
(1) am required to log in to a Google account, and
(2) get this pop-up: "Notebook loading error.  There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again."
  and buried in the displayed error is: "403 This file cannot be downloaded by the authenticated user."

This confuses me about the behaviour of Colab notebooks vs. other Drive files. Ordinarily, the "anyone with a link can view" on a Drive file does not require the viewing user to be logged in to a Google account.  That's confusion #1.  Confusion #2: why is Colab trying to "download" anything at all, as indicated in the 403?  I assumed the file would be viewable within Colaboratory within the user's browser, just as it is for the notebook owner.

I would like to invite (non-coding) colleagues to view my Colab notebook, with or without a Google account, and without any particular coding or Google savvy. Any ideas on how to do this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, Superduper, did you find the answer? I am dealing with the same problem... If you were able to find the answer, can you share with us? It is really annoying... the option says "Anyone who has the link can access. No sign-in required.". I believe this was working some weeks ago...

Comment: Not yet, hamagust.  I gave up for now and started looking at other options via https://www.dataschool.io/cloud-services-for-jupyter-notebook/
So far Azure seems closest.  But I would really like to use Colab, though, so I'm still hoping for an angel to chime in here.

Comment: I just realized that this happens when "Disable options to download, print, and copy for commenters and viewers" is selected in advanced options... I was able to share the notebook by deselecting this option...

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this is useful until a better solution is available...

This happens to me when "Disable options to download, print, and copy for commenters and viewers" is selected in advanced options...

I was able to share the notebook by deselecting this option...